# UICollectionView to DetailViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView of buttons that when pressed calls the function DetailEvent1. That function is supposed to open a new view which has details of the event. The only problem is I cannot figure out the line of code that pushes the data. Here is the code for the Collection View

```
[(UIButton *)self.EventButtons[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(DetailEvent1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And here is the code for the DetailEvent1:

```
    -(IBAction)DetailEvent1:(id)sender{

    TableDetailViewController  *objDetail = [[TableDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:objDetail];
    [self.view addSubview:objDetail.view];
}
```

And finally in the ViewDidLoad on the TableDetailViewController:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{
      lblTitle.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

If someone can help me get the data to pass from the CollectionView to the new ViewController I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation on Storyboard segues. Basically you have to drag a segue from your collectionview item to the detailView. Assign that segue an id.

On code, you have to implement a method called prepareForSegue, where you can initialize the destination viewController depending of the indexPath you tapped on.

I'd suggest you watch the iTunesU course on iOS programming posted by Standford University.

Comment: I am using Xib and not storyboards, is that going to be a problem?

Comment: Absolutely no if you know how to do it. But Storyboards are much easier to implement and to handle.